# UIImagePickerController: How do get file size while recording a video?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way for me to get the file size of the currently recording video as it's being recorded? I'm guessing the file is sitting in a tmp directory, but I'm not sure how I would determine which file it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I think catching it in NSData object and then calling 'length' method of NSData class might lead you in proper direction.

Comment: "[...]but I'm not sure how I would determine which file it might be."